# Where to put Spring context file for a Maven/Java project with no WEB-INF directory?

Tags: java, spring, maven, configuration

I want to use spring for a non-web Java project. Where should the context file go? How do I identify their locations to the Spring container?

I'm sure there are various choices, but with a web application it is typical to put things in `WEB-INF`, and to declare the locations in the `web.xml`. How is this done in a stand-alone app?

Comment: As an addition: [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it in a `resources` folder. And use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to load them. Use packages as your java classes use. E.g. `src/main/resources/com/myapp/somemodule/context.xml`.

Answer (score 8):

location : `src/main/resources/`

then you can be precise by adding directories like `moduleName/spring-application.xml`